# How to connect an external API to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, api

Currently in internship, I must realize a site under WordPress, however the customer wants the call of an external database to increase the content of its pop ups

I have to look on the web but nothing has really answered my problem, I really do not see how to call my external API in order to display it in the pop up of the customer knowing that the customer absolutely wants to use Elementor for the pop up data display

The API I want to use is https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all, it has little documentation and I am new to the job

So I would like the data just displayed for the pop-up Elementor of the customer in a drop-down list, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Show some code on what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I get it right that you need to display the values returned by the API in a dropdown in your popup?

You can either do this by JavaScript or PHP, depending on how your popup is generated.

Via JavaScript (or jQuery), you can simply fetch all of the entries of the API by using [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and modify the dropdown element to show your desired values.

```
$.get( "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

For PHP, you can fetch the data of the API as well and decode the JSON to a PHP array. After that, you can loop over it, generate a dropdown or whatever you want.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
$contents_arr = json_decode($contents);
```

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: That's all, thank you very much,
Do you know if it is possible to call this function via a short code on Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, because WordPress shortcodes are "just" mapping PHP functions. You can follow this [guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in the WordPress Codex and add my PHP code above to the shortcode handler function. Nevertheless, you need to think about if it's ok for you if every time the shortcode is inserted/the page is visited, a call to the API is started. Another alternative is to cache the result of the API and only fetch new entries every e.g. 1 minute.

Comment: Thank you very much and thank you for taking the time to explain and answer me

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as accepted and feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: And how to clean data display ? It's possible ?

Comment: I responded to your new post. Let's continue the discussion there.